# Different behaviour of Nautilus in Unity Launcher and Gnome 3 shell

Tags: gnome, nautilus, unity-dash

Preparing for the change from Unity to Gnome Shell in Ubuntu 17.10 I have installed Ubuntu Gnome on a spare PC.  Most differences in default behaviour are either acceptable or can be modified to suit my personal taste, but I can't figure out how get the Files launcher in the Activities Dash to behave as it did under Unity in 17.04 (and before).to org.gnome.Nautilus.

Specifically, In Unity the context menu after a right click includes shortcuts to the folders listed in ~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks. In Ubuntu Gnome these shortcuts don't show in the context menu.  I tried adding Actions of the form

```
[Desktop Action Documents]
Name=Documents 
Exec=nautilus --new-window  ~/Documents
```

to org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop, but although they showed in the context menu, Nautilus never opened the folder.

Also I had to do this to the system file /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop since when I put a copy in ~/.local/share/applications and modified it (so it also used a different icon) the system version was used in the Dash.  (This technique worked with Unity.)

What have I missed?

Comment: I've now installed Ubuntu 17.10 and can further clarify my question.  Launchers with context menus that I create work fine, but not if I try to use a modification of one of the launchers installed at installation---e.g. Files or Software.  I can not delete the original launcher and replace it with one of my own.  When I tried that with Files, launching nautilus just reinstalled the originally installed launcher in the Dock. Editing the desktop file in /usr/share/applications doesn't work either.  I can change the icon but the added Desktop Actions don't appear in the right click context menu.

Comment: I've been doing some more searching and I was reminded that the correct name for what I want is a quick list.  However I still haven't found how to add quick lists to desktop files in /usr/share/applications, though one in ~/.local/share/applications do work.

Answer (score 1):

After some more googling with some different variations of my search terms I have found a "solution," or more likely, just a work around that may not work for everyone.  Editing copies of the desktop files from /usr/share/applications that I put in ~/.local/share/applications I changed the line

```
DBusActivatable=true
```

to

```
DBusActivatable=false
```

and now every thing works.  I must admit I don't completely understand what this does. Also, be warned I'm using an X11 session.  I'll try to test this under Wayland, but I suspect I'll have some different problems because I use gksudo to launch Synaptic and its ilk.